# how to set up VPS server to allow access from outside only by VPN?

Tags: networking

l want to protect VPS server from outside and hackers to access to it ,  l want to access to VPS only by VPN.

What are the solution?
Thanks!

Comment: That's not possible. Your VPS needs to reachable from the internet in order to accept the VPN connection. You might limit the connectivity to mostly the VPN connection but cutting it off isn't possible unless it's on a separate network.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind Seth's comment:

> That's not possible. Your VPS needs to reachable from the internet in order to accept the VPN connection.

If you accept the fact that you need to at least expose the VPN port to the public Internet in order to connect to it, you can achieve this.

What you would do is:

- Set up a VPS
- Install a firewall (e.g. `ufw`)
- Install a VPN service (e.g. `openvpn`)
- Block all ports via the firewall, but allow SSH and VPN connections

How to do this depends on the particular OS you want to run. Here's [a tutorial for Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-18-04).

You typically want SSH connectivity too, not just VPN. Imagine the case where the VPN service on your server shuts down for whatever reason, then there's no easy way for you to connect to the VPN in order to SSH into the machine. It's a catch-22. The only way in would be through a virtual console that your VPS hosts should make available.

Also, when setting up SSH, make sure you disable password-based logins and use public-key-based authentication only.

Comment: l am already blocking all ports by  firewall  rule on Wan 
interface  ,but there is problem when l restart ir shunt down VPS server the rule deactivated and the ports  become opening (replay  on ping ). what is the solution ?                                   thank you .

Comment: You did not say this in your question. So I only answered the actual question you asked. Please ask a new question about this problem and include more detail, like which OS and which configuration you used for the firewall.